# T-online email client don't receive emails sent through Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are trying to send emails to t-online inbox but emails aren't getting delivered after 18th December,2019. Prior to this date, everything was working fine but all of a sudden emails stopped getting delivered. However, emails are getting delivered to other email clients.
Below options were tried to send emails :
1. Through Send test option in Marketing Cloud
2. Through Postman

Comment: I would suggest, first can you try sending the same email [with same HTML body and same SubjectLine] using PutsMail [https://putsmail.com/tests/new] and confirm, if the email is delivered! ....If NOT then you can debug within Marketing cloud.

Comment: Hi Vishal.. Thanks for the suggestion. yes, i got the email delivered to t-online through Putsmail. What should be my next step now ?

Comment: Can you also confirm, this is with respect to ONLY particular subscriber! [as the particular might have UNSUBSCRIBED] .... Also can you confirm if it might have landed to SPAM folder!.....

Comment: Yes, this is happening with a particular subscriber. In our case, its the email address of t-online email client. I checked the status and it says "Bounced".

Comment: Thanks for sharing the status..... As a last CREATE a new blank test email and see it if gets delivered..... For how to handle about BOUNCED emails, pls read the answer here ... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165399/how-hard-bounce-emails-are-treated-by-marketing-cloud

Comment: I already tried sending a blank test email but it doesnt get delivered too

Comment: I am sorry! that I am out of my debugging skills! .... lets wait until some one who may have faced similar issue and answer this :) ......FYI: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5

Answer (score 5):

T-Online is notorious for reputation-related delivery problems coming from Salesforce Marketing Cloud domains.

Case in point:
In the course of an IP warming, we literally sent 1 (one) email off a new, cold IP to t-online, and got a blocked bounce message back. 
Which clearly shows, t-online seems to block even if you don't "overpower" / send too much to them. For undisclosed reasons, to my knowledge.

So first thing - make sure you follow the rules. I understand that all other clients have no issue with your emails, but you can never be too safe. If you are sure everything is fine, skip the part between the "=".

===

- Ensure that you are not having a messy IP reputation to begin with, e.g. go to https://senderscore.org/.
- Check that you are not blacklisted or fail at best practices with your emails (tons of factors from DKIM to text/image ratio...). Having an SAP covers the DKIM part, btw., as it authenticates your domain for sending.

You can verify those topics with the following tools:

http://dkimvalidator.com/

http://www.mail-tester.com/

https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

If you are sure that you have no issues here (for our intents and purposes, you can ignore missing DMARC, which is often highlighted by mail-tester):

====

Now, verify what the issue is in your case: Query the _Bounce Data View for the BounceReason.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5

Just for full picture, query these fields:

BounceCategory

BounceType

SMTPBounceReason

SMTPMessage

I suspect you will find indications of block bounce "due to reputation" or similar reasoning.

So our situation likely is: We cleaned in front of our own door, found no issue with reputation, anyway we're blocked. That is the time to raise a support ticket with the deliverability team. Support will likely get in touch with t-online and try and resolve the issue "politically". This is a rather routine thing actually. Normally, you should see the issue resolved in a matter of a day or two.

hope this helps!